# step through a jsp file in Eclipse debug mode

Tags: eclipse, jsp, debugging

I'd like to be able to step through the execution of a jsp file in eclipse but I get "Source not found" message (note: I only get this meesage for jsp files, java files source is displayed in the debugger). So I click on "Edit source lookup path" and make sure the web folder where the jsps are is included. I click ok and the jsp source appears for a fraction of a second but then dissapears and again I see "source not found" error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What kind of launch is it? What kind of project? Can you edit the source lookup path in the launcher itself?

Comment: It's a java project running on Weblogic 10. How do I edit the source lookup path in the launcher?

Comment: What kind of launcher is it? How are you launching the project?

Comment: And while you're at it, which version of Eclipse is involved?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by launcher? I start the server by running the startup script. Remote debugging is set up in the script. I use an ant script to deploy the app to the server. Eclipse version is  Juno Service Release 2.